# Expose prototypes in object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Is there a way to expose an objects' prototypes through another object?

```
  var foo = function () {
    var foo = {
      bar: bar,
      boo: boo
    }
    return foo;

    function bar (age) {
      this.age = age;
    }
    bar.prototype.shoutAge = function () {
      alert('My age is ' + this.age);
    }

    function boo (age) {
      this.age = age;
      boo.prototype.shoutAge = function () {
        alert('My age is ' + this.age);
      }
    }
  }

  var foo = foo();
  var far = new foo.bar(13); // bar {age: 13}
  far.shoutAge(); // far.shoutAge is not a function

  var far = new foo.boo(13); // boo {age: 13} with __proto__
  far.shoutAge(); // alert('My age is 13');
```

In this code, the *'bar'* object is set up with prototype inheritance--but exposing bar loses the inheritance of *'shoutAge'*.

However, the *'boo'* object has the prototype declared inside of it and the outside function has access to the method *'shoutAge'*.

I don't think that the latter is a best practice even though it functions. So what would the best practice here be?

I don't want each instance of *'bar'* to have it's own *'shoutAge'* method, especially if there are potentially hundreds of instances of *'bar'*. Would you typically just create a separate object for *'bar'* instead of exposing it through *'foo'*?

Comment: Where is the inheritance here? Neither `bar` nor `boo` inherit from each other or `foo`.

Comment: `far` inherits from `bar.prototype` or `boo.prototype`

Comment: Try linting your program.

Comment: @torazaburo If instances can't inherit then the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-object-instances) must be wrong: "Object **instances** have no special properties beyond those **inherited** from the Object prototype object". I have no idea about classes because even with ES6 `class` syntax JS still doesn't have them, so not sure how they are relevant. When I say "a inherits from b" I mean `b.isPrototypeOf(a)` (assuming `b.isPrototypeOf` is `%ObjectPrototype%.isPrototypeOf`)

Comment: It is recommended to return at the bottom of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is just an order-of-operations issue:

```
var Foo = function () {

  function bar (age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
  bar.prototype.shoutAge = function () {
    alert('My age is ' + this.age);
  }

  var foo = {
    bar: bar,
    boo: boo
  }
  return foo;
}
```

I think this is because the `bar.prototype` assignment is never executed in your code. The `bar` function definition gets [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), so it's available in the object you return, but the prototype assignment is an additional statement after the `return` statement, and the control flow never reaches it. Simply moving the `return` to the end fixes the issue.

Comment: +1, good explanation. Might also be worth giving a link to what hoisting is, in case the OP is not aware.

Comment: @OmriAharon Added.

Comment: This made a lot of sense when I read it, and I've only briefly encountered hoisting in the past. Unfortunately this still throws that far.shoutAge is not a function. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j8ws41c/1/) as an example. *edit* Nevermind I was assigning this wrong in the fiddle, this does work.